# How to highlight text in Epub file loaded in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, objective-c, iphone, epub

I find the solution to search the text and highlight the specific word but 
how to highlight text in webview on touch ?

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: Need to highlight the text in ebooks loaded in webview just like the functionality in ibooks

Comment: Read this blog blog, perhaps it may help you. Thanks
http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/